# Use BarButtonItem as leftCallOutAccessoryView for MKPinAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, mkpinannotationview

The title pretty much explained it. Is it possible? I have tried to assign it like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(saveAnnotation:)];
pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftButton;
```

I have also tried casting it as a UIButton and as a UIView. The main reason I want this is because I want that little savebutton already intergrated in UIBarButtonSystemItemSave. How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible mainly because `UIBarButtonItem` is not a subclass of `UIView`.

Casting it to a `UIButton` or `UIView` doesn't work because casting does not *convert* an object from one type to another.  It just let's you inform the compiler that some variable can be treated as some other type (if that variable isn't really of that other type, you'll get an exception or it just won't work).

`UIBarButtonItem` is a subclass of `UIBarItem` (which is a subclass of `NSObject`) and is designed for use only in a `UIToolbar` or `UINavigationBar`.

I don't recommend trying to put a `UIToolbar` in a callout just to use `UIBarButtonItem`.
[Here's a look-alike workaround using UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015694/iphone-how-can-i-use-an-uibarbuttonitem-style-without-the-uitoolbar) but a segmented control may not look right in a callout either.

I suggest using a regular `UIButton` with a custom image or with button type `UIButtonTypeContactAdd` (blue circle with plus sign).

Comment: I ended up making a UIButton with UIBUttonTypeCustom with an image of a quicklymade savebutton. Thanks.